# Inequality of difference of product of coordinates.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality

Let $x=(x_1,\dots,x_r)\in\mathbb{R}^r, y=(y_1,\dots,y_r)\in\mathbb{R}^r$. How can we estimate $\left|\prod\limits_{i=1}^r x_i - \prod\limits_{i=1}^r y_i\right|$ in terms of $\max\limits_{1\leq i \leq r}\{|x_i-y_i|\}$?
My best estimate is $\left|\prod\limits_{i=1}^r x_i - \prod\limits_{i=1}^r y_i\right|\leq r \cdot\max\limits_{1\leq i \leq r}\{|x_i|,|y_i|\}^{r-1}\cdot\max\limits_{1\leq i \leq r}\{|x_i-y_i|\}$ but this is not the optimal estimate.
If for example $r=1000$ and $\max\limits_{1\leq i \leq r}\{|x_i|,|y_i|\} = 1$ for every $1\leq i \leq r$, then of course $\left|\prod\limits_{i=1}^r x_i - \prod\limits_{i=1}^r y_i\right| \leq 2$ but from the estimate above we get $\left|\prod\limits_{i=1}^r x_i - \prod\limits_{i=1}^r y_i\right|\leq 2000$. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is $n$ here? Perhaps $n = r$?

Comment: Oops my bad, yes $n=r$ and $x=(x_1,\dots, x_r)$.

Comment: I don't think the question per se is difficult. But the question is written ambiguously. For example, what are variables, what are parameters? Are the terms $\max |x_i|$,  $\max |x_i-y_i|$ or $|x_i|$ given?,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "best estimate" cannot be improved.
You can think of the following as a counterexample:\
Let $N$ be a very large number.Take for simplicity $x_1=x_2=2N$
and $y_1=y_2=N$. Then $|x_1 x_2-y_1 y_2|=3N^2$  but $\max{|x_i-y_i|}=N$.

Optimizing the coefficient is not easy. Let us see if we can get a stronger estimate in terms of the coefficients:

When $r=2$ the triangle inequality gives
$$|x_1 x_2 - y_1 y_2|=|x_1 x_2-x_1 y_2 + x_1 y_2 - y_1 y_2|
\leq 
|x_1||x_2-y_2|+|x_1-y_1||y_2|\leq 2\max\{|x_1|, |y_2|\}\max\{|x_1-y_1|,|x_2-y_2|\}
$$

We can continue using mathematical induction on $r$
and ultimately get

$$|x_1 \cdots x_r - y_1 \cdots y_r|\leq r\max\{|x_i|,|y_i|:1\leq i\leq r\}^{r-1}\max_{1\leq i\leq r}\{|x_i -y_i|\}.$$

Comment: In this case it should be: $r=2, \max\{|x_i-y_i|\}=N$ and $\max\{|x_i|,|y_i|\}^{r-1} = 2N$. From the inequality: $|x_1x_2-y_1y_2|\leq 4N^2$.

Comment: (1) The example given with $r=2$ can be done analogously for any integer $r\geq 2$, this should be clear.            (2) Yes, exactly. I am showing you that (up to a constant) your estimate cannot be improved ! You cannot replace $\max\{|x_i|,|y_i|\}$ by something smaller.

Comment: (1) Yes, of course.
(2) I am still missing something. In my opinion, if the estimator is "optimal" then it should exists at least one case (example) in which the inequality is an equality, so a better estimates cannot be found. Thanks again for the patience.